# Function Not Defined in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Hi I keep getting this error.  I am trying to make broken image icons not appear in an Angular Ionic app.  I have tis function but it keeps saying anonImg is not defined.  Im not sure how to define this?

```js
function anonImg(image){
  image.src = 'https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/anonymousUser.jpg';
     }
```

and my html is

```html
<ion-content class="climb-pics">
      <img ng-src="{{urlForImage(selected_.images)}}"/>
      <img onerror="anonImg(this);" ng-src="{{urlForImage(selected_.imageTwo)}}"/>
      <button type="button" class="button button-assertive" ng-click="closeModal(1)">Close</button>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </ion-content>
```

Should I be wrapping the function in a function or something? I just don't now what to do when I get the error "ReferenceError: anonImg is not defined"

Here is my controller code:

```
    .controller('ClimbController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Products', 'Climbs', '$ionicModal', '$localStorage', '$cordovaCamera', '$cordovaFile',
    function($scope, $stateParams, Products, Climbs, $ionicModal, $localStorage, $cordovaCamera, $cordovaFile) {

        $scope.product_id = $stateParams.productId;
        console.log('ClimbController: ' + $scope.product_id);
        // ClimbsController: 2

        $scope.urlForImage = function(imagePath) {
            console.log('imagePath: ' + imagePath);
            return Products.urlForImage($scope.product_id, imagePath);
        }

        var filename = Products.getFilenameFromLocalStorage($scope.product_id);
        console.log(filename);

        var climbId = $stateParams.climbId;
        var areaId = $stateParams.areaId;

        if (!isNaN(climbId)) {
            climbId = parseInt(climbId);
        }

        if (!isNaN(areaId)) {
            areaId = parseInt(areaId);
        }

        $scope.selected_ = {};
        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.details = true;
        $scope.data = '';
        $scope.noteParams = {
            text: null
        };

        // looping though all data and get particular product
        $scope.selectClimb = function(areas){
            areas.forEach(function(data) {
                if(data._id == climbId){
                    $scope.selected_ = data;
                }
            });
        }

        // get all posts // try some function to get a single produt from server
        $scope.getPosts = function(){
            Products.loadGuidebook(filename).then(function(data) {
                // NOTE: data = the whole feed.json file
                console.log(data);

                // data = feed.json file

                var climbs = [];
                data.areas.map(function(area) {
                    if (area._id === areaId) {
                        climbs = area.climbs;
                    }
                });
                $scope.selectClimb(climbs);
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }

        // picture slider logic
        $scope.allImages = $scope.images;

        //hide div with broken images
        anonImg = function(image){
            image.src = 'https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/anonymousUser.jpg';
        }

        $scope.load();
        $scope.getPosts();
    }
])
```

Comment: post your controller code

Comment: of course, you can't use function in html if you don't assign this function to scope, so you should set scope.nonImage = function (){blablalbla;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not posted the Controller code, You should have $scope in your controller and the function should be defined as,

```
$scope.anonImg = function(image){
  image.src = 'https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/anonymousUser.jpg';
}
```

Comment: all that does is brakes my controller

Comment: here is controller